# Circular dependency with updateValueAndValidity on dynamic validator

Tags: angular

I have an issue adding dynamic validator to form fields.
So I need to have validation on fields only if one of them has value. So if user enters value in any of the three field it should trigger requiredIf validator on all fields, but then I have:

> ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

But if I don't use updateValueAndValidity() it will not apply validators that I have set in setValidators();

Is there any solutions for this issue, the code is the following:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    ...

    this.mainForm.get('CargoWidth').setValidators([requiredIf(this.f['CargoLength']), requiredIf(this.f['CargoHeight'])]);
    this.mainForm.get('CargoLength').setValidators([requiredIf(this.f['CargoWidth']), requiredIf(this.f['CargoHeight'])]);
    this.mainForm.get('CargoHeight').setValidators([requiredIf(this.f['CargoLength']), requiredIf(this.f['CargoWidth'])]);

    this.onApplyValidators();
}

onApplyValidators() {
    this.f['CargoLength'].valueChanges
        .subscribe(value => {
            if (value === undefined)
                return;
            this.f['CargoWidth'].updateValueAndValidity();
            this.f['CargoHeight'].updateValueAndValidity();
        });

    this.f['CargoWidth'].valueChanges
        .subscribe(value => {
            if (value === undefined)
                return;
            this.f['CargoLength'].updateValueAndValidity();
            this.f['CargoHeight'].updateValueAndValidity();
        });

    this.f['CargoHeight'].valueChanges
        .subscribe(value => {
            if (value === undefined)
                return;
            this.f['CargoWidth'].updateValueAndValidity();
            this.f['CargoLength'].updateValueAndValidity();
        });
}
```

Comment: updateValueAndValidity has two options: onlySelft and emitEvent https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#updateValueAndValidity, see if you can play with these two properties

Comment: I've tried with this options, but the problem is if the value of some field is changed, it triggers the update on two other fields if any of them has a value already then it will trigger the update of the first field again, so I have an infinite loop. I need suggestion for another approach or some way to fix this.